# Concatenate two df with same kind of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two df.

df1:

```
         date   a
0   2021-12-15  0.16
1   2021-12-16  0.16
2   2021-12-17  0.16
```

df2:

```
         date   b
0   2021-12-16  0.17
1   2021-12-17  0.17
2   2021-12-18  0.17
```

I want this df as output

```
         date   a    b
0   2021-12-15  0.16 NaN
0   2021-12-16  0.16 0.17
1   2021-12-17  0.16 0.17
2   2021-12-18  NaN  0.17
```

I'm trying to use both concat `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1` and merge `df1.merge(df2,on=['date']` but I'm not able to find a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function.

You want to do:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='date', how='outer')
```

[This link](https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/) explains well the different types of merge possible.

Comment: True man, I tried but I have some problem in the data in my df and I was thinking it was duplicating some results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a concat, what you really want to do is an outer merge on the date. So, what you could use is the following :

```py
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on='date')
print(df)
```

For more info, consult this [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). You'll find plenty of examples and use cases.